# creating a dynamic graph using jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, charts

I have been working on a student performance app, I was asked to design a graph which will hold infomartion of a student based on thier performance each day.  I Tried many graphs plugins available out there, nothing seemed to do the task for me.
The pointer needs to have colors based on the percentage they acquired each day.
Bad: Red
Ok: Yellow
Good: Blue
excellent: Green
[image]

Comment: Have you tried http://www.jqplot.com/ ?

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend these http://www.jqplot.com/

http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/top-jquery-chart-libraries-interactive-charts/

Answer (score 3):

It seems to be possible with www.jqplot.com

you need your own [linerenderer](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/jqplot-lineRenderer-js.html)

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/jqplot-users/Ki1O0roEyno

almost on the bottom of that topic you can find two downloadable 'google docs' (js) with the code inside

Answer (score 2):

High charts allows this but you might be even better off building your own simple solution. Check out Rafael or d3, both would let you do this easily.

Answer (score 1):

[FusionCharts XT](http://fusioncharts.com/) ships with a jQuery plugin.

It's pretty easy to use, as shown in their [documentation](http://docs.fusioncharts.com/charts/contents/?jQuery/Overview.html).